# performance: order in pandas, or database?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a group or rows which I extract from a database, and then use them to build a pandas dataframe with datetime index. Pandas will round datetimes to specific resolutions, fill missing values etc.

The question is: when constructing a dataframe with datetime index from rows, *does pre-ordering the rows affect pandas' performance*? Should I order the rows by datetime in the database query before constructing the dataframe, or it doesn't affect the speed of initializing the dataframe, and I should let pandas take care of ordering?

Comment: How is created `DataFrame` ? In loop? Or with pass array for data, index, columns, with no loop ?

Comment: Dataframe.from_records([...])